# Json.Net Combine 2 Properties on Serialization

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I'm still fairly new to Json.Net and (de)serializing. I have an object which has a few fields

```
public class Person {
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
}

var p = new Person() {
    Id = 123,
    FirstName = "John",
    LastName = "Doe",
    Address1 = "456 Main St",
    Address2 = "Apt 2"
}
```

I need to serialize to the following json

```
{
    "id": 123
    , "fullName": "John Doe"
    , "street": "456 Main St Apt 2"
}
```

And deserialize that to

```
// Person.Id = 123
// Person.Address1 = 456 Main St Apt 2
// Person.Address2 = null

// we are ok not trying to split the 'street' into both 'Address1' and 'Address2'
```

I'm not sure the best method to do this. Do I need to use a `Converter`, `ExtensionData`, `Constructor`, or something else I haven't found because I don't know how to search for it ;)

Any help and examples would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While @Alan Buchanan's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45510245/286618) and @Brian Rogers [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45511125/286618) show great solutions, these did not accomplish what I needed in a simple way.

What worked best for me was to use `OnSerializing` and `OnDeserialized`. If I am doing something wrong, could so this better, or should be doing something different, please let me know.

**NOTE:** I understand that upon `Deserialization` the field `Address2` will be empty, and `Address1` will be a combination of what `Address1` and `Address2` used to be, but that is ok for our implementation.

```
public class Person {
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("fullName")]
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("street")]
    public string Street { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public string Address2 { get; set; }

    [OnSerializing]
    internal void OnSerializing(StreamingContext context) {
        Street = (Address1 + " " + Address2).Trim();
    }

    [OnDeserialized]
    internal void OnDeserialized(StreamingContext context) {
        Address1 = Street;
    }
}

// C# Object
var p = new Person() {
    Id = 123,
    FirstName = "John",
    LastName = "Doe",
    Address1 = "456 Main St",
    Address2 = "Apt 2"
}

// Json to output and consume
{ "id": 123, "fullName": "John Doe", "street": "456 Main St Apt 2" }
```

Answer (score 3):

To combine the two properties you could add a property like the one below:

```
public string FullName => FirstName + " " + LastName;
```

Of course, you'll want some logic for handling nulls etc.

You can decorate your class with attributes which will determine how the property names will be serialized. Your class could end up looking something like this:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Linq;

public class Person {
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("fullName")]
    public string FullName
    {
        get
        {
            return FirstName + " " + LastName; 
        }
        set
        {
            if (value.Contains(" "))
            {
                var split = value.Split(' ');
                FirstName = split[0];
                LastName = string.Join(" ", split.Skip(1));
            }
            else 
            {
                FirstName = value;
            }
        }
    }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

The JsonProperty attributes allow you to set the name of the property when it is serialized, while the JsonIgnore attributes tell the serializer not to include those properties in the output.

You can then get your JSON using:

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(person);
```

Comment: OP clearly states that he's already using JSON.net. No need for the extra instructions regarding Newtonsoft, they're the same thing

Comment: Thanks Alan, I do use Newtonsoft.Json (I learned yesterday most searches come up with Json.Net since it's the same thing) =) However, I do have some concerns because I do have other fields I need to serialize/deserialize which follow a similar pattern and don't wish to have it setup this way. I'll update my question to reflect this.

Comment: Sorry, I tend to simplify the question so it's not so large/complex, but then I realize when given answers that I *should have* made it complex. However, Your answer is definitely worthwhile for other scenarios I have.

Comment: @RoLYroLLs No problem. You will have to tell the serializer how to combine the properties somewhere so if not on the class I'm not sure where you can do it. Hopefully somebody else will have a solution :)

Comment: Thanks. From what I see, I think I *should* use `OnSerializing` but I haven't gone through enough examples to figure it out properly, or if I am even on the right track. I too hope someone would help at least point me in the right direction.

Comment: Alan, Using this method, what happens when I try to deserialize the Json `{"fullName": "John Doe"}` to the `Person` object? Would it be `John Doe` or would it be `null` since `FirstName` and `LastName` are not deserialized?

Comment: @RoLYroLLs You could try adding a set to the property which would split the fullname into the first name and last name. Not perfect as many names don't split easily this way but depending upon your requirements it may suffice. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @RoLYroLLs I've edited my answer. The code to split full name into the two name fields is a bit crude but hopefully the concept is clear.

Answer (score 3):

@Alan Buchanan [shows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45510245/10263) a nice simple way to achieve what you described in your question.  However, if you don't want to add additional properties to your class, then you'll need to use a custom [`JsonConverter`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter.htm) instead.  Here is an example of how you can write it:

```
class PersonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(Person);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        Person person = (Person)value;
        JObject result = new JObject();
        result.Add("id", person.Id);
        result.Add("fullname", (person.FirstName + " " + person.LastName).Trim());
        result.Add("address", (person.Address1 + " " + person.Address2).Trim());
        result.WriteTo(writer);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JObject obj = JObject.Load(reader);
        Person person = new Person();
        person.Id = (int)obj["id"];   // assuming id will always be present in the JSON
        string fullName = (string)obj["fullname"];
        if (fullName != null)
        {
            string[] parts = fullName.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, 2);
            // if there's only 1 part, I'm assuming it is the first name
            if (parts.Length > 0)
                person.FirstName = parts[0];
            if (parts.Length > 1)
                person.LastName = parts[1];
        }
        person.Address1 = (string)obj["address"];  // don't bother trying to split address
        return person;
    }
}
```

You'll notice the `PersonConverter` class contains three methods, all of which are required to be implemented by the `JsonConverter` abstract base class it inherits from: `CanConvert`, `ReadJson` and `WriteJson`.

The `CanConvert` method tells Json.Net that this converter handles `Person` objects.  This method may or may not be called by Json.Net depending on how you use the converter.  More on this later.

`WriteJson` is responsible for creating the JSON for the target object during serialization.  You can see here that I am using a [`JObject`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm) internally to build up the JSON using data in the `Person` class.  You can also call methods on the writer directly instead of using a `JObject`, but I find it a bit more cumbersome that way.

`ReadJson` handles the reverse: reconstituting the object from the JSON during deserialization.  Again, I use a `JObject` as an intermediary to get the data from the reader before splitting it out into the new `Person` instance.

If you only need to serialize and not deserialize, you can override `CanRead` to return `false`, and then just make `ReadJson` throw a `NotImplementedException`.  Similarly, there is a `CanWrite` property you can override if you only need to deserialize but not serialize.

There are two ways to use a `JsonConverter`: you can either pass an instance to the serialize/deserialize methods (either via method parameters or `JsonSerializerSettings`)...

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(p, new PersonConverter());
```

... or you can use a `[JsonConverter]` attribute to tie the converter to your class:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(PersonConverter))]
public class Person 
{
    ...
}
```

If you use the former method, then Json.Net calls `CanConvert` to determine what type(s) your converter can handle.  If you use the attribute, then `CanConvert` is never called because Json.Net assumes you would have specified the correct converter type in the attribute for the target class.

Here is a round-trip demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/EGok23

Comment: Thanks! This does seem like the way I may have to be doing it versus `OnSerializing`. I'll test it out and let you know how it works out.

Comment: Brian, let me ask you, for this `converter` placed at the `class` level, will I need to add **ALL** of the properties I want to (de)serialize or only those I wish to transform?

Comment: I tested my thoughts on your fiddle example and yes, I do need to include all the fields on that converter. Is there another way to only manipulate certain properties? I have objects with lots of properties that are not worth having to add to this converter for only 1 or 2 fields like this.